# Accessing External Final from project directory ASPX

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to access the types file from the project directory for the web root directory. Currently it only accesses it from the C:/, how can I have it access this file from the web root.

I would like the file to be in the project folder as types.txt.

```
    Dim fs As StreamReader
    Dim rdr As FileStream = New FileStream("/types.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    fs = New StreamReader(rdr)
    While Not fs.EndOfStream
        Dim line As String = fs.ReadLine() 'reads each line in file 
        Dim line2 As String = fs.ReadLine() 'reads each line in file 
        Dim final As String = line + " types at " + line2 + "%"
        mortBox.Items.Add(final) 'adds each lines to combo box

        'adds values to array list, this will allow the list to grow with new entries to the file
        arrayT.Add(line)
        arrayR.Add(line2)

    End While

    rdr.Close() 'closes open file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Server.MapPath("~/types.txt")`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for details.

The tilde character "~" is replaced with the path to the root of your web application.